# Can you activate a method on an Area2D node with the player's raycast2D in Godot?

Tags: game-development, godot

I created a sort of old style jrpg movement system with a 3 character party. The first character (the player) uses a raycast for checking of surrounding tiles and movement.

I want the player to come close to a shop tile and hit a button to open a dialog.
Player is in the middle, shop is above him, like so:

[image]

How would I activate a custom function on the shop tile?

I tried using raycasts and signals. The shop is an Area2D tile.
Is it even possible to trigger an Area2D on_entered signal with a raycast?
The default signals seem to be incorrect for this use, but so do custom signals.

There is probably something very simple I'am missing.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check what the raycast is colliding with. Since it looks like you are placing an Area2D on top of a TileMap, why not make the shop a StaticBody2D instead of a tile, and attach the shop script. It would be typical for game objects other than the walls to not be in the TileMap.

Somewhere with your player's movement code:

```
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("interact"):
        var collider = raycast.get_collider()
        if collider != null:
            if collider.has_method("open_shop"):
                collider.call_deferred("open_shop")
```

I am assuming here that the raycast is properly updated already in your movement code, either by the raycast property `enabled` being true, or having a call to `force_raycast_update()`.

Here, `raycast` should be replaced with any reference to the player's Raycast2D, and `"open_shop"` should be replaced with the function name (still as a string literal) from the shop script you wanted to call.

Comment: Yes, thank you. This helped me. I didn't realize there were such methods. For anyone using c#: You can even cast the object to an interface and call the method directly, without using CallDeffered().

Comment: @StepanMichalek You should use `CallDeferred`, I would not recommend calling other objects functions from physics process or process.